# struct.error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, lzw

Реализую алгоритм LZW на Python. При кодировании mp3 файла возникла следующая ошибка:

```
output_file.write(pack('>H', int(data)))
struct.error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535
```

Функция, где производится запись закодированных данных в файл:

```
def writeFile(self, path, some_data):
        #Запись в файл
        if self.mode == 'pack':
            #Запись закодированных данных
            output_file = open(path + '.lzw', 'wb')
            for data in some_data:
                output_file.write(pack('>H', int(data)))
```

Как решить данную проблемму?

Comment: полный текст ошибки добавьте

Comment: Значит `int(data)` вышло за границы этого диапазона. Проверяйте что вы там пишите, и должно ли оно вообще туда помещаться.

Comment: Дополнил ошибку

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать данный блок перехвата исключения:

```py
try:
    output_file.write(pack('>H', int(data)))
except struct.error:
    output_file.write(pack('>I', int(data)))
```

[Источник](https://github.com/google/enjarify/issues/36)

Comment: Файл сжиммается, но после разжатия сатновится больше и не проигрывается.